# How to know which control does a graphics object belongs to?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a method to draw something and I want to change the size of the `Control` that have `Graphics` object in the method.

**I mean something like that:**

```
    class Drawer
    {
        public Drawer()
        {

        }
        public void Draw(Graphics grp)
        {
            grp.Owner.Width = 100;
            grp.Owner.Height = 200;
            //...
            //Draw something
            //...
        }
    }
```

But as you know `Graphics.Owner` doesn't exist. How can I do that?

Comment: You would have to pass the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not an option. Better to pass the control if you can. And make sure to dispose the graphics object:

```
public void Draw(Control ctrl)
{
    ctrl.Width = 100;
    ctrl.Height = 200;

    using(Graphic g = ctrl.CreateGraphics()) 
    {
        //...
        //Draw something
        //...
    }
}
```

Or else pass the control with the graphics:

```
public void Draw(Graphics grp, Control ctrl)
{
    ctrl.Width = 100;
    ctrl.Height = 200;  
    //...
    //Draw something
    //...   

}
```

Comment: Your Draw method should never dispose of the graphic object since it was *passed* to it.  That's the responsibility of the caller.  CreateGraphics is for very specific scenarios since it won't DoubleBuffer and is easily erased by minimizing the form.